# Sum over first elements in pandas DataFrame column that contains a list of tuples returns ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum

I have a pandas DataFrame that has a column that contains a list of tuples. I want to get the total number of times the first element of the tuple is equal to 1 for each row of the DataFrame.

Assume my DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3],
                       "tuple_list": [[(1, 3), (1, 46), (4, 5)], [(2, 2), (1, 4)], [(3, 5), (69, 4)]]})
```

I expect the resulting DataFrame to look like this:

```
{"id": [1, 2, 3],
 "tuple_list": [[(1, 3), (1, 46), (4, 5)], [(2, 2), (1, 4)], [(3, 5), (69, 4)]],
 "first_1": [2, 1, 0]}
```

I tried this:

```
df["first_1"] = sum(i == 1 for i, _ in df["tuple_list"])
```

But this gives:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How to solve this? Am I not allowed to use the DataFrame column like that in a sum operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`

```
df["tuple_list"].apply(lambda x: sum(i[0] == 1 for i in x))
```

Comment: Ah I understand. Intuitive, this is quite strange for me to understand. The apply should work on the elements of the list right?

Comment: If you enjoyed answering this question, feel free to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_ones(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item[0]==1:
            count += 1
    return count

df['first_1'] = df['tuple_list'].apply(lambda x: count_ones(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However, I find Yefets solution a little more elegant